# How to remove border on image button

Tags: image, button, tkinter, border

*I am using the Tkinter library.*

I used images on labels, to use as buttons.

Unfortunately there's a white border around the image. But they aren't there on the image itself.

Same problem occurs wether I am using a tkinter Button or Label.

I tried to set borderwidth=0 and highlightthickness=0 already and it doesn't work.

[image: Buttons]

[image: green button]

[image: pieces label]

[image: length label]

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem (I use Archlinux with Xfce desktop), when I use `tkinter.Label(root, image="image.png", borderwidth=0)`, there is no border. But you can try to set the background of the Label to the same color as the one of the window, the border should then disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of j_4321.

I fixed it by setting the background color of the label to the background color of my GUI.